# If value = text?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation, if-statement

I'm trying to validate some data and I was wondering is it possible to encode an if statement so that if there is a text value entered instead of a numeric value that it does not crash?

Obviously the standard message indicating that an incorrect message has been entered.

I'll write an example here:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your height in centimetres please.");
Console.WriteLine("My height is: ");
dHeight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
if (dHeight == xxxxxx?)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Sorry incorrect data entered, please enter a numeric value");
 dHeight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
 }
```

What would I need instead of this as I am not sure how to phrase it/if it is indeed even possible.

Comment: Note a couple of other issues: you say 'please' twice in the first request, and also the first request is for height, but then the second is for weight!

Comment: Thanks Rufus, it's correct on the actual project file, I just messed up copying it over, thanks for highlighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with `double.TryParse` method which will return false if your value cannot be parsed.

```
double result;

if (double.TryParse(yourstirng, out result))
{
    //your string is double do something with the parsed value
    result++;
} 
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry incorrect data entered, please enter a numeric value");
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing paren on your if condition.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use `TryParse`, and then if it fails, prompt them again. Note I also added some retry logic here, so that the user cannot proceed until they enter a valid double.

In the code below, I capture their input in a variable (called `input`) and then use `double.TryParse` to try to convert it to a double. If the `TryParse` succeeds, then the double `result` will contain their converted entry. If it fails, then an error message is displayed and they can try again.

```
Console.Write("Please enter your height in centimeters: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
double result;

while (!double.TryParse(input, out result))
{
    Console.Write("{0} is not a valid height. Please try again: ", input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Thank you. You entered a valid height of: {0}", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDouble` uses `double.Parse` under the hood, which means that it will throw if an invalid format is encountered (ie. plain text).

Instead, use `double.TryParse` which does not throw if it fails (it simply returns false):

```
double dHeight = 0;
if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dHeight))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Some Error Message");
}
else
{
    //Parse succeeded! Value is in dHeight.
}
```

Comment: Can you pass Console.ReadLine to TryParse like that, or did you mean to invoke the method with Console.ReadLine()?

Comment: @Swoogan Nope; I just missed the () when writing it. Thanks for catching that!